# How can I search for interior doors with shoji paper inserts between glass lites?

Tags: wood, doors, glass

We are remodeling a house which has a few doors with 20 glass lites that look like they have shoji paper between the glass panes. They look like the 15 or 18 panel frosted glass doors one might find in Home Depot but the lites are the special type (almost looking like a Japanese shoji door). I have been searching using every combination of phrases on google with no luck - like door with glass lites with paper inserts, shoji doors with glass, etc. What would I search for to find these doors?

[image: Shoji style solid core cherry door]
[image: Closeup of lite with Shoji paper]

Comment: Are the muntins between the glass panels (i.e. 2 glass panels), or outside—does the door have individual windows (i.e. 40 glass panels)?

Comment: Between the glass panels. but I don't know if they are 40 glass panels or 2 panels with a full length shoji paper sandwiched inside and the thin dividers stuck on the outside. It could be a great and inexpensive way to customize a standard door though!! Thanks!

Comment: Lumicor makes resin panels with all kinds of stuff sandwiched in. Apparently Simpson builds these in. https://www.builderonline.com/products/simpson-door-co-s-lumicor-doors_o  Expect to pay — lumicor is expensive all by itself.

Comment: Oh hang on, the new pic makes me think I misunderstood how the doors are built.  Looks to me like a single pane of frosted glass with muntins on each side of the pane.  I do think you're going to have to go custom here, unless you can roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a 20-light door (2 columns of 10 glass panes), and that's the phrase I'd search on. Of course you'll also find four columns of five panels with that search.

Presumably you'll also want to match the wood and finish.

You may have trouble finding an exact match unless you can identify the manufacturer of the ones you now have.

Or you could go with something similar-but-different, which might or might not look more deliberate than a not-quite match.

As a last resort, there are places one can order custom doors, which can probably replicate these. I am guessing cost on the order of US$1000 per fully custom door, but that is purely SWAG estimate. You might get away cheaper if you have a friend who does woodworking and would be interested in helping you build your own doors.

(I have an old wooden storm door witb 16 lights, removed from service. I'm considering repurposing it as a multiple picture frame, for a group of 16 related images.)